# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out with JRE 1.7.0_25

Tags: java, sockets

My project is client-server architecture that AP server use JBOSS, through java webstart to launch Swing/AWT application on client site.
My customer ask upgrade JRE from 1.6.0_16 to 1.7.0_25 but weird error occurred.
Under JRE 1.6 everything is fine, but it fails under JRE 1.7.

Here is console log

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.checkUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance
Legend

Here is my JSP file

spec="1.0+"

codebase="http://<%=request.getLocalAddr()%>:<%=request.getServerPort()%>/start"

href="webstart.jsp">

```
<title>XXX</title>

<vendor>XXX</vendor>

<description>XXX</description>

<description kind="short">XXX</description>

<offline-allowed/>
<shortcut online="true">      

<desktop/>      

<menu submenu="XXX"/>    

</shortcut>

<%

    Properties dbProp = new java.util.Properties();

    dbProp.load(new FileInputStream("SystemConfig.properties"));

    String initialContext = dbProp.getProperty("INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY");...
%>
```

```
<j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-dsa -Xnoclassgc -Xms128m -Xmx512m"/>

<jar href="jar/XXX.jar"/>...
```

```
   <argument><%=initialContext%></argument>...
```

```
<all-permissions/>
```

Comment: You also need to share the code.

Comment: "Read timed out" indicates a problem with network configuration. Check the firewall and proxy settings that your customer uses.

Comment: I don't set up any firewall and proxy setting, so it's weird.

Comment: it works under JRE 1.6, but fails as soon as upgrading to JRE 1.7, thanks a lot.